# ECR image push AWS CodeBuild issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1). Reason: exit status 127

Below is my buildspec.yml file

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws --version
      - $(aws ecr get-login --region ***-east-*)
      - REPOSITORY_URI=***********.dkr.ecr.***-east-*.amazonaws.com/repositoryname
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...          
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed
      - echo Pushing the Docker images...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo Writing definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name":"project-container","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > taskdefinition.json
artifacts:
    files: taskdefinition.json
```

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps someone else, for the work I'm doing inside my build scripts executed by CodeBuild. These are the IAM permissions I had to add (finding them one by one as I hit the error).

```
{
    "Action": [
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
        "ecr:CreateRepository",
        "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
        "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecs:UpdateService"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Effect": "Allow"
}   '
```

I'm sure there are more permissions that may be required if you're doing stuff I'm not doing in your builds. I'm pushing to ECR and forcing the Service (and the related tasks) to deploy the new image.

Comment: I had to add these permissions separately, since the AWS managed AWSAppRunnerServicePolicyForECRAccess does not contain all of these.  Fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Your post has inconsistent details, is that intentional? If not, it may be causing the problem. Your code snippet says:

```
$(aws ecr get-login --region ***-east-*)
```

Perhaps you purposely redacted the region (what's the point of that btw?) but why is it missing the `--no-include-email`? Higher up in your post, you do make reference to `--no-include-email`, so I know you're aware of it.

## Run the process outside of a subshell to get a better log

Rather than running it inside a subshell (e.g. `$(my command)`), for troubleshooting purposes, try running taking the subshell out so you can get better output. Report the results here so we can troubleshoot the error you get.

`aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1` <- try this temporarily

vs.

`$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)`

## Have you created an IAM Policy with ECR permissions for CodeBuild to use?

This is very important. CodeBuild needs permission to access ECR on your behalf. Here's an example I found on this blog article. It may need tweaking to your needs. http://beta.awsdocs.com/services/code_build/build_docker_images/

```
{
    "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

Comment: I have used the below code and now fixed previous issues.
`aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1`

Yes i have added mentioned policy. 

Now i am getting below error-

`COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .. Reason: exit status 127`

Comment: Great to hear that the original error you posted about is resolved! Please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: To fix your `docker build` error, we need more details than the `exit status 127`. So, please scroll up in the CodeBuild log and you'll get more details on the problem. You can paste it here or start a new SO post, if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region **-****-* | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin *****.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```